# Why does Django run server hang when using docker-compose up?

Tags: django, docker-compose

When I run docker-compose up, Django starts to load. It goes thru the about four steps. After it does a system check and identifies (0 issues), it stops at displaying the current date and time. This is the point where it just hangs. Nothing else happens.

```
C:\Users\********\Desktop\code\hello>docker-compose up
Creating hello_web_1 ... done
Attaching to hello_web_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | August 21, 2019 - 17:33:11
```

When I do docker-compose down, the system exits Gracefully(lol). Then I run docker-compose logs and it shows the correct info:

```
C:\Users\********\Desktop\code\hello>docker-compose logs
Attaching to hello_web_1
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | August 21, 2019 - 17:36:44
web_1  | Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'hello_project.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
web_1  | Watching for file changes with StatReloader
web_1  | Performing system checks...
web_1  | System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
web_1  | August 21, 2019 - 17:55:22
web_1  | Django version 2.2.3, using settings 'hello_project.settings'
web_1  | Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
web_1  | Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Here is what my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml look like:

````
#Dockerfile:

#Pull base image
From python:3.7-slim

#Set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

#Set work directory
WORKDIR /code

#Install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /code/
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

#Copy project
COPY . /code/

#*docker-compose.yml: 

web:
  build: .
  command: python /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
  ports:
    - "8000:8000"```
````

- note I'm using version 1 of docker-compose, that's why my web service is at the root of the file. I also omitted the version per Docker documentation.

Comment: are you able to hit http://localhost:8000?

Comment: I am able to hit localhost:8000 when i go thru my virtual env and use python manage.py runserver. It loads the page and shows my test homepage. Now when i exit virtual env and then run docker-compose i get the error i posted above. However when I do a compose-docker logs, it appears to say it did connected. 

*SEE LOG DUMP IN POST*

Comment: Sorry, what I mean is are you able to hit localhost:8000 after running `docker-compose up` (despite the lack of seeing the "Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/"). If not, could you try running in the background instead? `docker-compose up -d`

Comment: Oh okay I see what you mean. I thought that myself and tried to go to localhost after using `docker-compose up` but it still shows no connection. When i do `docker-compose up -d` it just shows `Attaching to hello_web_1` then goes directly to command prompt in pwd. Then when I go to localhost same result.

Comment: Yes, when you run in the background (with `-d`), you need to use a different command for the logs (`docker-compose logs`). Try running `docker-compose logs --tail=100 -f web` after you start the container.

Comment: Installed Windows 10 and upgraded docker. Everything worked good. It appears to be docker toolbox for Win7 is not compatible.